# How to read data from Firebase Realtime database using Flutter/Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Flutter and I would like to retrieve some data from my realtime database Firebase. I have the following data stored in the my realtime database Firebase:

[image]

How can I get each piece of information from it? For example I would like to get the name 'Tom' only?

Answer (score 1):

Reading through [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) you can see that how we read and write data from RTDMS firebase.

```
  static Future<List<PostModel>> getPost() async {
    Query postsSnapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child("posts")
      .orderByKey();

    print(postsSnapshot); // to debug and see if data is returned

    List<PostModel> posts;

    Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = postsSnapshot.data.value;
    values.forEach((key, values) {
      posts.add(values);
    });

    return posts;
  }
```

your can call this function at the time of build the widget or after any action

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users").onValue.listen((event) {

 final data = 
 Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value as Map,);

 data.forEach((key, value) {
     log("$value");
 });
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

if your data in RTDB is `Object`, you can use casting type from result object to `Map?` then, convert it to collection `.map()`. here example:

```
final resultDataRealtimeDatabase = item.value as Map?;

final Map<String, dynamic> userData = resultDataRealtimeDatabase.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key as String, value);

final userModel = UserModel.fromJson(userData);
```